# Algorithm Sequence classification(anomaly detection)

Tags: machine-learning

I have a problem statement where i am having many inputs lets say A,B,C,D.... and this inputs can take any real value(e.g A-a1,a2,a3, B-b1,b2). Now, i have file which will be have record of the all the inputs and there values at given point of time. I also know what should be the specific sequence for example A-a1,B-b1,C-c1. So, now my job would be to read the file and find whether anywhere the above sequence break. i.e. after A-a1,B-b2 came.

What would be the standard approach for solving this type of problems ? I have explained in simple terms but the inputs can be in 1000's and also the sequences will not be always simple it can contain many paths(for e.g sq1 - A->B->C->D..sq2 - A->B->E) etc. I am thinking of sequence classification but all the examples always state that we should have training data but for me there is no thing as training data it is a truth table.(It is other thing that many combinations can happen of the truth table)